# If $A$ an $B$ are finite, the the set of all functions from $A$ to $B$ is finite..

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

Suppose $A$ and $B$ are finite $\rightarrow$ $A \approx N_k$ $\land B \approx N_m$ 
then $A = (x_1,...,x_k)$ $\land B = (y_1, ..., y_k)$ Let $L$ be the set of all functions $A \rightarrow B$ , $\rightarrow f(x_1) = y_1 , ... , f(x_k) = y_k$ .
Can someone please say is that a proof or i have to add something?
How to prove that $P(A$ x $B)$  is finite? By P- i mean power set

Comment: No.  That is not a proof.  It is a statement of one possible function but only if k = m.  This isn't the only function.  There's also g(x_1) = x_2, and h(x_1) = x_3, etc.  And if |A| = k > |B| = m, what does f(x_{m+1}) equal?  You have proven:  If |A| = |B| then |P(A x B) $\ge 1$.  You need to prove a bit more than that.

Answer (score 1):

Given two finite sets, you can enumerate (i.e. count) the possible functions explicitly. I recommend you go ahead and try it when $A, B$ are small. In general, @user247327's answer is perfectly correct.

The reasoning you use is that, for $f:A\rightarrow B$ to be a function at all, it needs to be defined over every element of $A$. Once you've chosen where each element of $A$ goes, you have fully determined the function. So how many different ways can you define a function? Well, for each element of $A$, you can send it to *any* of the elements in $B$ - so for each element of $A$, there are $|B|$ many choices.

Now, as $f$ can be any old function (i.e. it doesn't have extra properties, like preserving some property of $A$), choosing where one element of $A$ goes doesn't affect where any of the other elements can go. So when you choose the first element of $A$, you have $|B|$ choices; then for each of those choices you have $|B|$ choices for where the second element goes! So if $|A|=2$, you have $|B|^2$ choices of function. In general, if $|A|=m$ and $|B|=n$, the total number of ways to define a function is $n^m$.

This is only vaguely related to the powerset of the product of $A$ and $B$. The powerset of $A\times B$ has size $2^{m\times n}$ (why?), and every function can be thought of as one of the subsets of $A\times B$, so $|P(A\times B)|\geq$ the number of functions from $A$ to $B$. However, there are plenty of subsets of $A\times B$ that aren't functions! For example, any subset that doesn't include some particular $a\in A$ in its domain can't be a function by definition, and similarly, if it includes two or more choices for where to send a particular element, it also can't be a function.

Now, it is possible to try and enumerate all subsets of $A\times B$ that have these properties, and that actually will agree with the answer we got in the first place! But this is a round about solution, because all we've really done is used the definition of a function (well-defined everywhere) in a different context, namely $A\times B$. I personally prefer the first solution as far more intuitive.

Answer (score 0):

If A contains m members and B contains n members, then there are $n^m$ functions from A to B.

Comment: This is definition of $P(A $ x $B)$ ?